# How to convert Windows filenames (from a checksums.md5) to *nix notation so I can use it on my shell with md5sum?

Tags: windows, linux, special-characters, md5, escape-characters

I have some `checksums.md5` verification files from an ntfs external drive, but using windows notation: `\` instead of `/`, spaces between file names (not escaped), reserved shell characters (like `(`, `&`, `'`, to name a few).

The `checksums.md5` has a bunch of checksums and filenames:

```
;Created by program
;2010

f12f75c1f2d1a658dc32ca6ef9ef3ffc  *My Windows & Files (2010)\[bak]\testing.wmv
53445e1a0821b790872e60bd7a166887  *My Windows Files' 2 (2012)\[bak]\testing.wmv
53445e1a0821b790872e60bd7a166887  *My Windows Files ˜nicóde (2012)\[bak]\testing.wmv
;Finished
```

I want to use this `checksums.md5` to verify the files that I've copied to my machine: but I'm on a Linux, so I need to convert the names inside `checksums.md5` from Windows to Linux to use the `md5sum` utility from the shell. The first line in my example would become:

```
f12f75c1f2d1a658dc32ca6ef9ef3ffc  My\ Windows\ \&\ Files\ \(2010\)/\[bak\]/testing.wmv
```

Is there some application for this (converting a file listing, from windows cmd notation, to linux shell notation) or will I need to create a bash script using sed that just "replaces" what is "wrong" with the filenames?

Comment: What is it you're trying to verify? Is it the NTFS filesystem itself?

Comment: No, the files that were copied to the external ntfs drive had a md5 checksum, I'm copying them again to the machine and want to verify the checksums, but the checksums.md5 is using windows file listing notation and I need to convert it to *nix. I've edited the question with more information and a concrete example.

Comment: That's **not** "Windows `cmd` notation".  If it were, the ampersand would be escaped with a caret.  That's just the raw unadorned pathname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i 's|\\|/|g' checksums.md5
```

The `md5sum` output format does not use *any* "shell notation" – neither `cmd` nor `sh`. Each line has exactly two fields (hash and filename) so no escaping should be required for file names.

The *only* difference is the usage of `\` versus `/` as the path separator in different systems. (Most Windows programs accept `/` too.) Just replace all backslashes and you're done.

Comment: I needed to add "./" at the beginning of the line as well since the checksums aren't with the full path... but thanks. Since it wasn't working, I thought it was the special characters, but your answer made me look for other problems (that's why I marked it as accepted). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not for nothing but md5deep is available for both Windows and Linux and it's 100% cross-platform compatible.  Check it out on http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/